# UndefinedMetricWarning. Nowhere i'm able to get the answer

Tags: python, multilabel-classification

In my code i'm calculating f1-score for my multi-labelled dataset by writing the following command:

```
f1_score_results.append(f1_score(y_train[col], y_pred_train[col_idx], average='macro'))
```

This code is giving me the output but error is also coming which is given below.

[image: 1]

I also wrote the following code

```
print(len(np.unique(X_train)))
print(len(np.unique(X_test)))
print(len(np.unique(y_train)))
print(len(np.unique(y_test)))
```

The output that i m getting is :

[image: 2]

Kindly help me how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens, because you have a lack of testing data. Therefore the warning, saying hey i dont have enough test data. So i cant give you the f-score, so i am just gonna put a 0.0 value since i dont have anything to campare too.
What you should  do is try to increase, your y_train and y_test dataset size. Maybe imposing less conditions on then